# Ubuntu Live CD Customization minimal size

Tags: customization, cd

I've been looking into building a custom Ubuntu live CD with only the necessary apps and a light graphical desktop so I can boot into ram. I was interested in using Ubuntu minimal CD but I learned that it's not a live boot cd. So I started looking into https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization
Now, the instructions are great and easy to follow. However, I want to build a live disk that resembles much like the minimal install cd. Does anyone have any ideas on what I can do to slim down a custom ubuntu live cd? What packages should I remove? There are a ton of packages listed when I run the command:

```
dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -nr | less
```

Again, I just want to build a Ubuntu live CD with a graphical desktop that doesn't eat up memory and basically no packages except for file manager, terminal, settings, software update and whatever else is needed. Thank you!

Comment: Is [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/) suitable for you?No compilers , no games and almost no useless packages with a light desktop environment.Its ISO size is about 1.1 GB for 18.04 (about half of the original Ubuntu) . Also you can take a look at the older versions of Lubuntu if the up-to-date packages don't matter for you.The ISO size of those are indeed smaller.

Comment: I guess I could try doing a custom live cd build from lubuntu. I'm not sure if I can use the same instructions from the ubuntu.com site.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why do you want to use Ubuntu? I mean there are other small distributions that you can use like raspbian , tiny core and puppy with small ISO size.But you may have problems regarding the package management in the latter two but raspbian is debian-based so there shouldn't be any problem.